# Print FILENAME if 1 conditional (out of 2 options) is found outside 'square brackets'

Tags: regex, bash, awk, sed, grep

I was wondering how to print filename base on finding one pattern (out of two options) outside square braquets in several files.

This is to say:

1. Look for two patterns (*patterns are words repeated into several files*) and iff both are at the same line of a file, print FILENAME.
2. These two words are outside square brackets.
3. These two words are located through its `NF`. 1st word is in `$(NF?NF-2:"")` or `$(NF?NF-1:"")`. 2nd word is in `$NF`.

Based on:

`-F,`

`word1=Villa de Leyva`

`word2=Colombia`

`/^C1 /`

`($(NF?NF-2:"")==/Villa de Leyva/ && $NF==/Colombia/ ) || ($(NF?NF-1:"")==/Villa de Leyva/ && $NF==/Colombia/ )` IFF At the same NR

**Input**

```
File 1 with name: xx1

PT J
C1 [Ramirez, P.A.; Villa de Leyva, A.; Smith, W.] University Villa de Leyva, Villa de Leyva, Colombia
C1 [Antunez, P.; Howard, R.; Li, X.] University X, Villa de Leyva, Caldas, Ecuador
[Trujillo, A.; Santos, K.; Wassermann, J.] Instituto Y, Villa de Leyva, Sweden
PY 9999

File 2 with name: xx100

PT J
C1 [Ramirez, P.A.; Villa de Leyva, A.; Smith, W.] University Villa de Leyva, Villa de Leyva, Chile
C1 [Antunez, P.; Howard, R.; Li, X.] University X, Villa de Leyva, Caldas, Colombia
C1 [Trujillo, A.; Santos, K.; Wassermann, J.] Instituto Y, Villa de Leyva, Sweden
PY 9999

File 3 with name: xx333

PT J
C1 [Ramirez, P.A.; Villa de Leyva, A.; Smith, W.] University Villa de Leyva, Villa de Leyva, Chile
C1 [Antunez, P.; Howard, R.; Li, X.] University X, Villa de Leyva, Caldas, Mozambique
[Trujillo, A.; Santos, K.; Wassermann, J.] Instituto Y, Villa de Leyva, Sweden
PY 9999
```

**Expected Output**

```
xx1
xx100
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ awk -F, 'NF>2 && $NF~/Colombia/ && ($(NF-2)~/Villa de Leyva/ || $(NF-1)~/Villa de Leyva/) {print FILENAME}' *
xx1
xx100
```

#### Explanation

The above works by combining four conditions.  If the conditions are met, then the file name is printed.

The first required condition is:

```
NF>2
```

This requires that the line have at least three fields.

The second required condition is:

```
$NF~/Colombia/
```

This requires that the last field contain `Columbia`.

And, finally, one of the following two conditions must be met:

```
$(NF-2)~/Villa de Leyva/
$(NF-1)~/Villa de Leyva/
```

Together, these require that `Villa de Leyva` appear in either the second to last or third to last fields.

#### Passing in search parameters from the shell

Here, the names to search for as passed in to `awk` as variables, `var1` and `var2`, on the command line:

```
$ awk -F, -v var2="Villa de Leyva" -v var1="Colombia" 'NF>2 && $NF~var1 && ($(NF-2)~var2 || $(NF-1)~var2) {print FILENAME}' xx*
xx1
xx100
```

Comment: Thank so much John1024. Your answer works fine to me. Have a good day : )

Comment: John1024, a last question. Do you know how can I pass variables? I'm trying with `awk -F, -v var1="villa de leyva" -v var2="colombia" 'NF>2 && $NF~/var1/ && ($(NF-2)~/var2/ || $(NF-1)~/var2/) {print FILENAME}' xx*` and it does not work. Thank in advance for helping me out.

Comment: @Alejandro Very close.  `$NF~/var1/` will match the characters `v`, `a`, `r`, and `1`.  To match the value of `var1`, use `$NF ~ var1`.  See updated answer for full working solution.

Answer (score 1):

To check if the pattern exists in a single file you could use this:

```
cat /tmp/b | perl -pe 's/\[.*?\]//g' | grep -P "Villa de Leyva,[^,]*,* Colombia"
```

This will return the line that matches your criteria.

If you want to look through multiple files loop through with a for:

```
  for i in $( ls file1 file2 ...); 
> do
> if cat $i | perl -pe 's/\[.*?\]//g' | grep -q -P "Villa de Leyva,[^,]*,* Colombia"
> then
> echo $i
> fi
> done
```

Oneliner:

```
for i in $( ls *);  do if cat $i | perl -pe 's/\[.*?\]//g' | grep -q -P "Villa de Leyva,[^,]*,* Colombia"; then echo $i; fi; done
```

Comment: Thank so much Susan, your answer works ok. +1 for your creative. But not chose because it takes too much time 
`real 0m31.421s
user 0m16.960s
sys 0m41.388s
`

Comment: Hi Alejandro, My answer was generalizing for every case - making sure the strings didn't appear in square brackets and that the two strings were no more than a field apart. That's why I had to be creative. But thank you so for +1 :)

Answer (score 1):

Grep should suffice, the -l option prints only the file name, and the pattern you looking for should not span lines if you anchor it with ^ and $ like:

`grep -l '^.*Villa de Leyva.*Colombia.*$' xx*`

```
Output: 
xx1
xx100
```

Comment: Thank too much A.Danischewski. Your answer was the fastest one `real 0m0.074s
user 0m0.046s
sys 0m0.028s` Would it be too much if I ask you how your answer works? Speccialy: `.*Villa de Leyva.*Colombia.*`

Comment: The beginning part ^ anchors the regular expression to the beginning of the line, then .* matches anything until Villa de Leyva the next .* matches anything until Colombia and the last .* matches everything to the end of the line anchor $.